# Como testar se a porta de um host está aberta?

Tags: python, python-3.x, redes, ping

Como descobrir se determinada porta de um computador da rede está aberta?

Quanto mais eficiente for o método, melhor. Precisarei escanear uma subnet inteira várias vezes por dia.

Comment: amigo você pode usar scapy / python-nmap ou socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html):

```
import socket

def test_port(ip, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((ip, port))
    sock.close()

    if result == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

A única maneira de saber é tentar abrir uma conexão. Se a porta não estiver aberta sua aplicação recebe uma resposta imediata (erro 1225 no Windows e 111 no Linux, correspondente a um segmento RST do TCP).